# Xamarin.Forms DataTrigger not working

Tags: c#, xamarin.ios, xamarin.forms

I'm trying to set DataTrigger on my control in Xamarin.Forms, but I cannot get it working.

I have Property in ViewModel with OnPropertyChange execution for `bool IsValid`

I have tried:

DataTrigger in Xaml:

```
<customControls:NumericTextBox
    Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="2"
    Text="{Binding StringValue, Mode=TwoWay}"
    IsEnabled="{Binding IsEditable}"
    XAlign="End">
  <customControls:NumericTextBox.Style>
    <Style TargetType="customControls:NumericTextBox">
      <Style.Triggers>
        <DataTrigger TargetType="customControls:NumericTextBox" Binding="{Binding IsValid}" Value="true">
          <Setter Property="TextColor" Value="Red"/>
        </DataTrigger>
      </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
  </customControls:NumericTextBox.Style>
</customControls:NumericTextBox>
```

Getting exception: `The Property TargetType is required to create a Xamarin.Forms.DataTrigger object.`

DataTrigger in Control:

```
_item = new DataTrigger(typeof(NumericTextBox));
_item.Binding = new Binding("IsValid",BindingMode.Default,new NegativeBooleanConverter());
_item.Value = true;
Setter s = new Setter();
s.Property = TextColorProperty;
s.Value = Color.Red;
_item.Setters.Add(s);
this.Style.Triggers.Add(_item);
```

Exception: `Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation.`

I have tried also changing line : `this.Style.Triggers.Add(_item);` to `this.Triggers.Add(_item);`. This wasn't raising exception, but it just didn't worked.

In this last try, it even hits converter, but does not change TextColor of Control.

Am I doing something wrong? How to handle that?

Comment: I think you might be hitting a (known) issue: http://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/30465/using-datatrigger-in-xaml

Comment: SO there is no other way to handle that? it's one of most important feature :(

Answer (score -1):

I ran into this same issue.  As a workaround, instead of using a DataTrigger you could bind the TextColor property to a Color property in your ViewModel.  In the IsValid setter you could then set the color based on the value.

```
public bool IsValid
{
    get { return _isValid; }
    set
    {
        _isValid = value;
        MyNewTextColorProperty = _isValid ? Color.Blue : Color.Red;

        OnPropertyChanged();
    }
}
```

Comment: This is not an acceptable solution, the ViewModel should not know anything about the page's styling.